# SoapFault: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, drupal-9

I am having these errors below

SoapFault: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://xxxxxx.xxxx.xxx/xxxx/XxxxServices?wsdl=XXX.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://xxxxxx.xxxx.xxx/xxxx/XxxxServices?wsdl=XXX.wsdl" in SoapClient->__construct() (line 30 of /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/xxxx/web/modules/custom/xxxx/src/XXX/XXX.php).

Warning: SoapClient::__construct(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity " 'https://xxxxxx.xxxx.xxx/xxxx/XxxxServices?wsdl=XXX.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://xxxxxx.xxxx.xxx/xxxx/XxxxServices?wsdl=XXX.wsdl" in SoapClient->__construct() (line 30 of /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/xxxx/web/modules/custom/xxxx/src/XXX/XXX.php).

Warning: SoapClient::__construct(https://xxxxxx.xxxx.xxx/xxxx/XxxxServices?wsdl=XXX.wsdl): Failed to open stream: Connection timed out in Drupal\xxx\xxx\XxxxServices->__construct() (line 30 of opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/xxxx/web/modules/custom/xxxx/src/XXX/XXX.php)

My code like this

```
public function __construct(array $options, $qa = true) {
  foreach (['login', 'password'] as $item) {
    if (empty($options[$item])) {
      throw new \InvalidArgumentException("$item is required for " . __CLASS__);
    }
  }

  $wsdl = $qa ? __DIR__ . '/../../wsdl/qa.wsdl' : __DIR__ . '/../../wsdl/prod.wsdl';

  parent::__construct($wsdl, $options + [
    'authentication' => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'trace' => 1,
    'classmap' => static::$classMap,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Connection Timed Out. That means the server you hit to get the WSDL did not reply to your request. Is it firewalled? Try hitting that URL with a browser.

Comment: I am able to hit the server by browser. Also, I am only getting this error sometimes. So it doesn't work stable

Comment: Try turning the WSDL cache setting to something other than "NONE". This will insulate you from these periodic outages, and/or stop you from getting ratelimited because do you really need to re-download the service WSDL X times for every single request?